# Undefined reference to `get_string' compiling CS50 code

Tags: c, cs50

I'm a complete beginner and have no prior coding experince.
and most of the answer to this problem are in technical words, but I'm not able to understand them.
Please help in more begginer friendly language.

My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    string answer = get_string("What is your name");
    printf("Hello, %s\n", answer);
}
```

And after running it, got this.

```
> Executing task: C/C++: gcc.exe build active file <

Starting build...
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "C:\Users\MaNaS\Desktop\CS50x\C Code\0002.c" -o "C:\Users\MaNaS\Desktop\CS50x\C Code\0002.exe"
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MaNaS\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIpKhYX.o: in function `main':
C:\Users\MaNaS\Desktop\CS50x\C Code/0002.c:6: undefined reference to `get_string'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I'm using VS code and Mingw64.
I had downloaded CS50 library, and copied `cs50.c` & `cs50.h` to `C:\msys64\mingw64\include`

Comment: The error is from the linker, whose purpose is to tie together the results of compilation (individual object files and libraries). It says it cannot find the function `get_string`. This indicates that `cs50.c` file, where that function is presumably defined, has not been compiled, or that your compiler cannot find its object file. In particular, `cs50.c` does not belong in `include` - either it should be a part of your project (in `src` — in which case `cs50.h` should be there too), or it should be compiled to a library and put into `lib`.

Comment: You tagged cs50, so I assume you are aware that the class you are taking has a special setup. Presumably you are supposed to use a special library which does all those  cs50-specific functionalities which later will have to unlearn using. Did you get a manual for setting up your environment and building? Did your first exercises involve getting a cs50-specific HelloWorld built and running? Go back to those descriptions. Maybe ask your fellow students how they set things up.

Comment: You forgot to link with the CS50 library, e.g. add `-lcs50` to your compiler command line.

Comment: Which schools use this cs50.h header? I know nothing about it.

Comment: I'd like to know what a `string` is and does in that library too.

Comment: @GabrielStaples CS50 is some class at Harvard and `string` is `char*`. I wonder how you managed to not stumble over those questions in the past while getting >19k rep.

Comment: @Gerhardh, thanks. I managed to not see them by generally only answering questions > 8 years old, in particular questions pertaining _exactly_ to what I am working on in any given moment. After figuring out the answer to an old question, I post it as a new answer to the question if I think it adds more value, which frequently it does since sooo many questions have incomplete answers or answers which could be improved. I've received the [necromancer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer?userid=4561887) 74 times, for instance, doing this.

Comment: I think the issue of setting cs50 library in your project. Some how you need to compile it so your project can refer to it. I found a link that does without compiling the library. see this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N25b4LgOFyE&t=100s

Comment: You are not supposed to include `cs50.c`. Therefore I doubt you should put that file into your include folder.

Comment: @GabrielStaples "Which schools use this cs50.h header?" Bad schools. It teaches bad programming habits such as hiding pointers behind typedef. And as a result some 90% of all students asking about CS-50 here on SO have no clue about how pointers and strings work. So when hiring, we need to ensure that future C programmers haven't studied this Harvard crap class or they have to re-learn everything.

Comment: @Lundin I'm a bit torn here. [The course cs50](https://pll.harvard.edu/course/cs50-introduction-computer-science?delta=0) teaches 3 entirely different languages plus html/CSS. Its focus is on "abstraction, algorithms, data structures, encapsulation, resource management, security, software engineering, and web development" -- it is not a C programming 101. Providing an abstraction level so that one can discuss interesting things instead of language quirks makes sense here. Also, being a university and not an applied science college, students are supposed to learn the technicalities themselves.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin How I'll add ` -lcs50 ` to my compiler command line, and where I'll add it.

Comment: @Amadan How I'll compile `cs50.c` because when I tried to run that file
It showed `undefined reference to 'WinMain' ` and `1d returned 1 exit status` And please explain `In particular, cs50.c does not belong in include - either it should be a part of your project (in src — in which case cs50.h should be there too), or it should be compiled to a library and put into lib.`

Comment: @manaslogin Generally if you are using `gcc` then your normal compile string should be similar to `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o outputnamefor.exe source.c -lnameoflib(s)` where you can compile multiple sources (e.g. `source1.c source2.c ...`) and you can include a language standard (like `-std=c11`) and you can include an optimization level (`-O0` to `-O3` and `-Ofast`, that's `capital oh#` not `zero#`). You can add `-g` to generate debug output for use with `gdb`. If you don't have `libcs50.so` built, you can include `cs50.c` as one of your source files instead.

Comment: There are many more options you can include. Suggest `-Wshadow` to catch any shadowed variable names and `-Werror` to treat warnings as errors. You can look at the [gcc Manual - 3.1 Option Summary](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html) to get an idea for how many there actually are.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and performed the following steps to be able to compile my code on Linux:

1 - Install [**CS50 Library for C**](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/):

```bash
 curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/cs50/repo/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
 sudo apt install libcs50
```

2 - Add the following variables to your `.bashrc` file:

[**How to Set Environment Variables in Linux**](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-linux/)

```bash
 export CC="clang"
 export CFLAGS="-fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow"
 export LDLIBS="-lcrypt -lcs50 -lm"
```

Obs: To access the `.bashrc` file type `nano ~/.bashrc` in your terminal and type the code above in the last line of the file and save

3 - Restart **bash**:

```bash
 source ~/.bashrc
```

4 - Install **clang**:

```bash
 sudo apt-get install clang
```

5 - Compile your source code:

```bash
 make code_name
```

6 - Run your machine code:

```bash
 ./code_name
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I feel like a few people trying to help you don't understand the CS50x course. Your code matches mine, but looking at your output, it appears you are not running your project in Codespaces. Per the project specifications, your work should be done in Codespaces. Read through the beginning of the problem for instructions on how to set up your Codespace. Don't worry about everyone talking about how `string` is `char*` and that `get_string` does not exist, when you run your code in Codespaces, your line `#include <cs50.h>` will fix all of this.

Answer (score 0):

Run the `update50` command in the terminal of codespace and rebuild as per the following instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found this on cs50 stackexchange which worked for me.
Keep both the files cs50.c and cs50.h in the same directory where your program file is

Run this in the terminal:
gcc mario2.c -o mario2 cs50.c
where mario2.c = your_program, mario2=executable_name, and cs50.c is where it gets the library from.

Original answer posted [here](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/7291/how-do-i-install-the-cs50-library-to-my-local-os)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32669153)

Answer (score 0):

type in terminal only: gcc hello hello.c cs50.c This code worked for me and that error back you it got because you did not link it on the command

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34835144)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Codespace for CS50 version at Visual Studio Code.
Here is the link to the website:

https://cs50.harvard.edu/ap/2021/

Here is the link for the IDE:

https://ide.cs50.io/

Answer (score -1):

First of all: Welcome to stack overflow!

### Recommendation

Respect for choosing C as your first programming language :D Be prepared for a wild adventure with C!

I'd really recommend you to read a programming book about C. I've heard that the book [The C programming language](https://math.ecnu.edu.cn/%7Ejypan/Teaching/ParaComp/books/The%20C%20Programming%20Language%202nd.pdf) is a good book to learn C but I haven't read it (I read [this german book](https://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/c_von_a_bis_z/000_c_vorwort_001.htm#mj764cb3fd439d3b95d1843e7c7d17f235)). Those books will give a good explanation and a good introduction to get into C programming.

### Rough answer to the question

Here is a compact summarize what the problem is, since your question is why you're getting this error
but I won't get into too much detail since I highly recommend to read a C book,
because I'm sure that they are explaining that better than me.

Anyways, let's take a look into the compiler error message:

```
C:\Users\MaNaS\Desktop\CS50x\C Code/0002.c:6: undefined reference to `get_string'
```

this means that it doesn't know where the implementation of `get_string` is.
Also `string` doesn't exist as an explicit datatype. You'll have to use an (so
called) "array of chars". `char` stores a single character and string is just a
row of them.