# CS50x Course get_string is undefined

Tags: c, cs50

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cs50.h"

int main(void)
{
    string answer = get_string("What's your name? ");
    
    printf("Hello, %s\n", answer);
}
```

I'm doing a course on edX called CS50's Introduction to Computer Science and in week 1 lecture 1 I have to write some code that asks the user what his/her name is and says "Hello" with the name after it, I've been fixing this for over 2 hours now wasting away time. I downloaded the cs50 library and put it into my vscode.

[VScode files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dweeU.png)

Here's the syntax error too.

```
PS C:\Users\Felip\Documents\Microsoft VS Code\New Code> cd "c:\Users\Felip\Documents\Microsoft VS Code\New Code\CS50IntroClanguage\" ; if ($?) { gcc name.c -o name } ; if ($?) { .\name }
C:\Users\Felip\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYgzUcR.o:name.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `get_string'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
PS C:\Users\Felip\Documents\Microsoft VS Code\New Code\CS50IntroClanguage>
```

Comment: Please do not post text logs as an image - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: I changed the text log to text now kaylum, thanks for correcting, retired ninja I got it from github, I tried GetString and got this: name.c: In function 'main':
name.c:6:21: warning: implicit declaration of function 'GetString' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     string answer = GetString("What's your name? ");
                     ^~~~~~~~~
name.c:6:21: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
C:\Users\Felip\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCjPk5Z.o:name.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `GetString'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Based on the command line you've shown `cs50.c` isn't being compiled and linked. It would need to be something like `gcc name.c cs50.c -o name`. I'm not sure how VSCode handles multiple files but it seems many struggle with it.

Comment: I got: gcc name.c cs50.c -o name name.c: In function 'main': name.c:6:21: warning: implicit declaration of function 'GetString' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] string answer = GetString("What's your name? "); ^~~~~~~~~ name.c:6:21: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] C:\Users\Felip\AppData\Local\Temp\cc44NCYd.o:name.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `GetString' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status                                  from trying to put that command you gave me

Comment: You need to change back to `get_string`.

Comment: Ok I changed back to get_string, now what do I do? I'm back where I started with my problem

Comment: If it doesn't work with `gcc name.c cs50.c -o name` I don't know what to tell you. I don't use VSCode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined reference to \`get\_string'. I'm a very beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71507578/undefined-reference-to-get-string-im-a-very-beginner)

Answer (score 0):

You need `#include <cs50.h>` instead of `#include "cs50.h"`. "" means that the file you're including is in the same folder as your code. <> Means that it's installed on the system.