# How do I add CS50 library to MinGW compiler?

Tags: c, cs50

I have already downloaded cs50 library and copied the (cs50.h and cs50.c) files to the working file. But when I try to run a program containing (git_string..or something else) I can't run it. and I get this error:

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\khale\AppData\Local\Temp\ccco4iR5.o:credit.c:(.text+0x6e): **undefined reference to `get_string'**
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Is there a better compiler than this?

Comment: cs50.c would need to be compiled and linked. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic foo.c cs50.c -o foo.exe`

Comment: Show the exact command you use to compile and link your program

Comment: I used code runner extension

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined reference to \`get\_string'. I'm a very beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71507578/undefined-reference-to-get-string-im-a-very-beginner)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this link helps. Follow all the steps and the cs50 library for Clang will be installed on your PC..
https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/