# I am getting an error when running c in vscode

Tags: c, debugging, cs50

So when I am running a simple `C` program asking user's name it gives an error. Saying,

```
the prelaunch task c/c++ :gcc.exe build active file terminated with exit code -1
```

My program was,

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cs50.h"

int main(void)
{
    string name = get_string("what is your name? ");
    
}
```

I am a total noobie in coding. Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Was it actually linked successfully? Is that _all_ the output you get?

Comment: linked? . yes that was all the output and there was 3 options for debug anyway, show errors and abort .so when clicking on debug anyway gives another error saying "launch program c :\user\user\cs50\mario.exe does not exist"

Comment: Yes, linked. First a program is compiled, then it's linked with libraries and object files. If the program doesn't exist, my guess is that linking failed. Have you added the cs50 library to your project? If you haven't compiled `cs50.c` into a library I think you'll manage by just adding `cs50.c` to your project.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes i added the cs50.c and cs50.h file to my project folder .

Comment: @TedLyngmo Do we have to make a new file like when we use cloud (make filename ) in vscode ?? does c run on its own when we  run it??

Comment: `cs50.h` only needs to be `#include`d in your code like you do now. `cs50.c` needs to be compiled. Adding it to the project folder is probably not enough. You need to add it to the VS Code project as a source file, just like your own source file that you've shown in the question.

Comment: still showing the error

Comment: Then you did it wrong.

Answer (score -2):

[image: according to these information as standard]

You must add `printf` function, like this :`printf("name: %s\n", name);` to get the output, as well as you must add return 0 at end of the main code block as your return data type of main is `int` so it require an `int` in return.

after modification you code may look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cs50.h"

int main(void)
{
    string name = get_string("What is your name? ");
    printf("name: %s\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: condition : **cs50.h** file must be locally in that location(`folder`) where you are making this above file in which you written code , as well if you manually compiling through console (like : cmd / powershell) you must  check those files are in same directory in which you are operating /opened the conslole , to do that you must use `cd`(**change directory**) to locate the directory where both file are available ...

Comment: if you are using mingw so you may compile it manually by typing `gcc filename.c -o filename.exe` 

then 

`.\filename.exe `

Comment: Adding a `printf` to the program will not solve the issue OP is asking about. OPs build fails.

Comment: @Redhope when i tried "gcc mario.c -o mario.exe" its saying --undefined reference to `get_string'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status--

Comment: @Subin [link-Undefined-reference-to-get_string-compiling-CS50-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71507578/undefined-reference-to-get-string-compiling-cs50-code) i think this will help you . 

The error message "undefined reference to `get_string`" is a `linker error`. It typically occurs when the `linker` (ld) is unable to find a reference to a function or symbol that is used in your code.

There are a few possible explanations for this error:
**1.Missing function definition
2.Missing library or module
3.Typo or incorrect function name**

Comment: @Redhope Thank you so much. it took me a while but it got solved