# Does "libcs50" and "Clang" can be installed on Git Bash Terminal at VS Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio, clang, cs50, git-bash

As a beginner in C programming, I'm trying to download and install the "libcs50" library and "clang" compiler on my git bash terminal from VS Code based on one of the questions that corresponds to my other problem. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71507578/undefined-reference-to-get-string-compiling-cs50-code#:~:text=this%20means%20that%20it%20doesn,just%20a%20row%20of%20them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71507578/undefined-reference-to-get-string-compiling-cs50-code#:%7E:text=this%20means%20that%20it%20doesn,just%20a%20row%20of%20them).

Although the environment variables are added to my `.bashrc` file

```
export CC="clang"
export CFLAGS="-fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow"
export LDLIBS="-lcrypt -lcs50 -lm"
```

Nonetheless, I cannot install the cs50 library

```
$  curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/cs50/repo/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
bash: sudo: command not found
```

```
$  sudo apt install libcs50
bash: sudo: command not found
```

Also, the clang compiler cannot be installed because `bash: sudo: command not found`

```
$ sudo apt-get install clang
bash: sudo: command not found
```

I have tried to find a solution on YouTube, stack overflow, and Google but to no avail because these solutions are very old and complex.

So, how can I install `libcs50` and `clang` on Git Bash at VS Code?

Comment: As far is I could tell, someone at Microsoft wrote an article on how to get `mingw32` to work with VSCode, so I think that's the only reason why it's the default. `Clang` should work, too, but you'll need to follow the install instructions for Windows.

Comment: So you're saying the command `sudo apt install libcs50` worked but the command `sudo apt-get install clang` does not? I wouldn't expect either to work in git bash on Windows. It's just a shell not a complete operating system.

Comment: So, how to get `mingw32` to work with VSCode? @Neil

Comment: I think https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw and https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp provide a pretty good tutorial, but maybe the `cs50` has their own requirements.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to ditch git bash and work on WSL. Git bash is not a real development environment and shouldn't be used as such. It's just a simple utility shell intended to be able to use `git` and other simple commands.

Comment: Are you trying to install libcs50 because you are studying the CS50 course?  Because otherwise, you should steer clear.  libcs50 is a must for the course, but it will stunt your growth as a C programmer.

Comment: I wonder how libcs50 will stunt my growth? Just asking though. @John Bollinger

Comment: In general, hacks intending to make learning C simpler are not necessarily best practices in production code.